JOLT Transformation: How to Conditionally Merge Two Fields and Retain Other Attributes?
I'm working on a JOLT transformation where I need to merge two fields, AccountNumber and EntityID, retaining only the non-empty value. In my input, one of these fields will always have a value, but never both. Additionally, I want to keep other relevant attributes in the output.
Here’s an example of my simplified input JSON with dummy data:
{
  "AccountNumber": "123456",
  "EntityID": "",
  "TransactionYear": "2023",
  "TransactionMonth": "03",
  "TransactionDay": "05",
  "TransactionHour": "10",
  "TransactionMinutes": "15",
  "TransactionSeconds": "30",
  "ComponentNumber": "12345",
  "Price": "250.00",
  "CurrencyCode": "USD"
}

Objective:
Merge AccountNumber and EntityID, keeping only the non-empty value. Since one of these fields will always contain a value, I want the output to reflect that without creating an array.
Retain other attributes: Keep TransactionYear, TransactionMonth, TransactionDay, TransactionHour, TransactionMinutes, TransactionSeconds, ComponentNumber, Price, and CurrencyCode in the output.
Here’s the JOLT spec I’m using:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "AccountNumber": "Temp.AccountNumber",
      "EntityID": "Temp.EntityID",
      "TransactionYear": "TransactionData.TransactionYear",
      "TransactionMonth": "TransactionData.TransactionMonth",
      "TransactionDay": "TransactionData.TransactionDay",
      "TransactionHour": "TransactionData.TransactionHour",
      "TransactionMinutes": "TransactionData.TransactionMinutes",
      "TransactionSeconds": "TransactionData.TransactionSeconds",
      "ComponentNumber": "NewPrice.ComponentNumber",
      "Price": "NewPrice.SpecialPrice.Price",
      "CurrencyCode": "NewPrice.SpecialPrice.CurrencyCode"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "AccountNumber": "=firstNotNull(@(1,Temp.AccountNumber), @(1,Temp.EntityID))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "Temp": ""
    }
  }
]

Problem:
The output I’m getting still contains AccountNumber as an array:
{
  "AccountNumber": ["","123456"],
  "TransactionData": {
    "TransactionYear": "2023",
    "TransactionMonth": "03",
    "TransactionDay": "05",
    "TransactionHour": "10",
    "TransactionMinutes": "15",
    "TransactionSeconds": "30"
  },
  "NewPrice": {
    "ComponentNumber": "12345",
    "SpecialPrice": {
      "Price": "250.00",
      "CurrencyCode": "USD"
    }
  }
}

Desired Output:
I want AccountNumber to be a single value (either AccountNumber or EntityID), not an array, while retaining all other attributes:
{
  "AccountNumber": "123456",
  "TransactionData": {
    "TransactionYear": "2023",
    "TransactionMonth": "03",
    "TransactionDay": "05",
    "TransactionHour": "10",
    "TransactionMinutes": "15",
    "TransactionSeconds": "30"
  },
  "NewPrice": {
    "ComponentNumber": "12345",
    "SpecialPrice": {
      "Price": "250.00",
      "CurrencyCode": "USD"
    }
  }
}

Question:
How can I modify my JOLT spec to ensure that only the first non-empty value between AccountNumber and EntityID is retained without resulting in an array, while still keeping all other attributes?
Thank you in advance!

You can use the following transformation spec :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "AccountNumber|EntityID": "Temp.AccountNumber",//form the array named "AccountNumber"
      "*tion*": "&(0,1)tionData.&", //TransactionData -> replicate the first 
                                    //asterisk, eg. "Transact" by &(0,1) 
      "*": "NewPrice.&" //others
    }
  },
  {//combine the components of the "AccountNumber" array 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Temp": {
        "AccountNumber": "=join('',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1 is :


Thank you for your response. I understand that the value will be added to the array. Could you please suggest a Jolt spec with logic that checks if the AccountNumber is available, and if it's empty, it should take the value from EntityID instead? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

You're welcome @Ryan . For the current case you already stated that retaining only the non-empty value. In my input, one of these fields will always have a value, but never both . So, you dont need to check emptiness, in any case the values merged under AccountNumber by the curent solution.
